# Change other objects inside model's custom save method in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Well, I have two django models for storing Questions and Questionnaires. Every question is inside a questionnaire. Every Question should have a field to store the order it is going to appear in a questionnaire. My questions is what is about the best way to handle changes in the order of a question.

The code have for the models:

```
class Questionnaire(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    time_creation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Question(models.Model):
    questionnaire = models.ForeignKey(Questionnaire, related_name='questions', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    order = models.IntegerField()
```

One way I thought of doing it was by overriding the save method for the Question model, like that:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    all_questions = self.questionnaire.questions.all()
    if (self.order == None or self.order > len(all_questions)+1 or self.order == 0):
        self.order = len(all_questions)+1 # starts in 1
    else:
        previous = all_questions.filter(order=self.order)
        if len(previous)>0:
            p = previous[0]
            p.order = self.order+1
            p.save()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It is kind of a recursive function, inside save() i verify if there is a Question with the same order number and increase it then call the save (inside the save), which will do the same for this object.

Is it a good way to solve the problem? Django has a few idiosyncrasies that i might not be aware of and might bite me latter. Should i use signals, maybe? Do it post save? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django provides a very simple mechanism through model meta options, namely [order_with_respect_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#order-with-respect-to).
I believe using it would already make things easier:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    questionnaire = models.ForeignKey(Questionnaire)
    # ...
    class Meta:
        order_with_respect_to = 'questionnaire'
```

This adds two methods to the `Questionnaire` model. Both let you handle the order of the `Question` objects using a list of `Question` primary keys.

#### Get the order

```
questionnaire = Questionnaire.objects.get(id=1)
questionnaire.get_question_order()
[1, 2, 3]
```

#### Set the order

```
questionnaire.set_question_order([3, 1, 2])
```

Please note that this operation will add an `_order` column to the database and implicitly set `ordering` to use this.

You can now implement all further business logic by manipulating the order list. Just an example helper for finding the order of a `Question` object:

```
questionnaire = Questionnaire.objects.get(id=1)
question_order = questionnaire.get_question_order()

question = Question.objects.get(foo='bar')
position = question_order.index(question.pk)
```

I am not sure if you should really go down that road (using an `order` field), but if you do, at least use a `PositiveIntegerField` and constrain it to be unique. I don't know where your inputs comes from but you should always try to sanitise them to a sequence, throw them in a list, and then set the order of the `Question` objects all at once.

Comment: You are right, using `order_with_respect_to` is the best way to do it. I had to make a few changes on my api for it to work, but now it is working fine, thanks!